Charles Proxy Certificate not downloading/installing on iPhone when I goto URL
I am having an issue. I have been trying to download the certificate to my iPhone (iPhone 14 Pro Max iOS 17.4.1) and when I go to the page, it just shows me the "Charles SSL CA Certificate Installation" and nothing auto downloads nor is there any link to download the certificate. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

What do you mean by "the page" my be https://chls.pro/ssl? If you just get a page without link to a certificate you have not set-up the proxy in iOS correctly (the iPhone doesn't use Charles).
